# Observer Design Pattern, do I have it backwards?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I am in a class that is implementing a Monopoly Game emulation, very simple, just prints out the results of each turn to the console for the user to see, eventually we will move it to a GUI but for now we are just S.o.P to the console each player's turn results.

These results are being printed from the Player class. The player class holds basically all the information needed to print in one place (ie. playerName, rollTotal, origSquareLocation, newSquareLocation).

I'm trying to wrap my head around the Observer Design Pattern and make the MonopolyGame Class an Observer and the Player Class the Observable. Is this possible or do I have it backwards because MonopolyGame Class is constructing the Players? Do I need to make a separate GameObserver Class to make this work?

Here is my MonopolyGame Class:

```
public class MonopolyGame {

    private static final int ROUNDS_TOTAL = 40;
    private static final int PLAYERS_TOTAL = 2;
    private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>(PLAYERS_TOTAL);
    private Board board = new Board();
    private Die[] dice = { new Die(), new Die() };

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     */
    public MonopolyGame() {

        Player p = new Player("Horse", dice, board);
        players.add(p);
        p = new Player("Car", dice, board);
        players.add(p);
    }

    /**
     * Method: playGame()
     * 
     * starts a new MonopolyGame for the assigned amount of rounds.
     */
    public void playGame() {

        for (int i = 0; i < ROUNDS_TOTAL; i++) {
            playRound();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method: playRound()
     * 
     * allows each player by iterator to take their turn for each round played.
     */
    public void playRound() {
        for (Iterator<Player> iter = players.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            Player player = iter.next();
            player.takeTurn();
        }
    }

} // End MonopolyGame Class
```

And this is my Player Class:

```
public class Player {

    private String name;
    private Piece piece;
    private Board board;
    private Die[] dice;

    public Player(String name, Die[] dice, Board board) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dice = dice;
        this.board = board;
        this.piece = new Piece(board.getStartSquare());
    }

    public void takeTurn() {

        // Roll the dice
        int rollTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
            dice[i].roll();
            rollTotal += dice[i].getFaceValue();
        }

        // place the Players piece in the correct location.
        Square newLoc = board.getSquare(piece.getLocation(), rollTotal);
        piece.setLocation(newLoc);

        System.out.println(getName() + " has rolled a " + rollTotal + " and landed on " + getLocation().getName()); 
    }

    public Square getLocation() {
        return piece.getLocation();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

} // End Player Class
```

Comment: Based on what you have, I think you have the right idea, but I think you basic structure is backwards.  It's not the responsibility of the player to know where it is within the context of the board and probably not even it's responsibility to make a die roll, but that could be argued.  The board would maintain information about the position of the player and move the player as required, the player would maintain information about, for example, things it owns and money it has, which the board would interact with based on the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is a possible use of the pattern. But a more natural (at least to me) usage of that pattern would be something like a "ConsolePrinter" or "GuiBoardWindow" beeing the Observer, and the Game (or the players) beeing the Observables. Since the main idea of the Observer pattern is to decouple parts which are not directly related. The state of the game and the player objects are for me so essential, that you might not want to decouple them. At least not as long as neighter Player or Game is anything beside the actual model/entities for game mechanics.

Comment: I see, so @eckes you're saying add separate Observer classes (ConsolePrinter and GUIWindow) to watch what I want from either MonopolyGame or Player? It makes sense, I was hitting a wall before and wanted some feedback if I was grasping the concept right or if there were better ways to go about it making separate observer classes.

Comment: Yes, well of course only add it it you need it. If it works perfectly fine without a pattern, go for that. Any I somewhat agree, I would concentrate most of the logic in a central class and have Player only hold the different, well, player details. Unless you want the Player to be actually different "robots" simulating strategies.

Comment: The game logic might not go any further. This is the final iteration of this assignment and he did say any intense specifics other than to apply the observer pattern in some way to replace the average S.o.P. Thanks for being a sounding board!